# My function not working outside of another function scope even though I have imported it

Tags: javascript, webpack, scope, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to figure out whats going on with my code down below, I have imported my function using `import { getTodos } from './todos'` into another file called `views.js`. I'm trying to call `getTodos` in the top level of `views.js`, but I get an error that it's not a function (it's `undefined`). But once I try using `getTodos` inside a function in the same module, it suddenly works!? Why is it suddenly no longer undefined, and how can I fix the code so that it's defined where I want it to be?

My todos.js file which includes defining getTodos function:

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'
import { renderTodos } from './views'

let todos = []

const loadTodos = () => {
    const todosJSON = localStorage.getItem('todos')
    try {
        return todosJSON ? JSON.parse(todosJSON) : []
    } catch (e) {
        return []
    }
}


todos = loadTodos()

const getTodos = () => todos


const saveTodos = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
}


const createTodo = (text) => {

    if (text.length > 0) {
        todos.push({
            id: uuidv4(),
            text,
            completed: false
        })
        saveTodos()
        renderTodos()
    }

}

const removeTodo = (id) => {
    const todoIndex = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === id)

    if (todoIndex > -1) {
        todos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
        saveTodos()
    }
}

const toggleTodo = (id) => {
    const todo = todos.find((todo) => todo.id === id)

    if (todo) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
        saveTodos()
    }
}



export { loadTodos, getTodos, createTodo, removeTodo, toggleTodo }
```

My views.js file which Im trying to load getTodos in it then use it:

```
import { getTodos, saveTodos, toggleTodo, removeTodo  } from './todos'
import { getFilters } from './filters'

const todos = getTodos()
const renderTodos = () => {

    const filters = getFilters()
    const todosEl = document.querySelector('#todos')

    const filteredTodos = todos.filter((todo) => {
        const searchTextMatch = todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
        const hideCompletedMatch = !filters.hideCompleted || !todo.completed

        return searchTextMatch && hideCompletedMatch
    })

    const incompleteTodos = filteredTodos.filter((todo) => !todo.completed)

    todosEl.innerHTML = ''
    todosEl.appendChild(generateSummaryDOM(incompleteTodos))

    if (todos.length > 0) {
        filteredTodos.forEach((todo) => {
            todosEl.appendChild(generateTodoDOM(todo))
        })
    } else {
        const emptyMessage = document.createElement('p')
        emptyMessage.textContent = 'No to-dos to show, go ahead and add some!'
        emptyMessage.classList.add('empty-message')
        todosEl.appendChild(emptyMessage)
    }
}


const generateTodoDOM = (todo) => {

    const todoEl = document.createElement('label')
    const containerEl = document.createElement('div')
    const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button')
    const span = document.createElement('span')


    // Setup Container
    todoEl.classList.add('list-item')
    containerEl.classList.add('list-item__container')
    todoEl.appendChild(containerEl)

    // Setup Remove Button
    removeButton.textContent = 'remove'
    removeButton.classList.add('button', 'button--text')
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeTodo(todo.id)
        renderTodos()
    })
    span.textContent = todo.text


    // Setup Checkbox
    checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
    checkbox.checked = todo.completed
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        toggleTodo(todo.id)
        renderTodos()
    })
    containerEl.appendChild(checkbox)


    containerEl.appendChild(span)
    todoEl.appendChild(removeButton)

    return todoEl
}

const generateSummaryDOM = (incompleteTodos) => {
    const summary = document.createElement('h2')
    summary.classList.add('list-title')
    const plural =  incompleteTodos.length === 1 ? '' : 's'
    summary.textContent = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todo${plural} left`
    return summary
}

// Make sure to set up the exports

export { generateSummaryDOM, renderTodos, generateTodoDOM }
```

index.js file:

```
import { createTodo } from './todos'
import { renderTodos } from './views'
import { setFilters } from './filters'

// Render initial todos

renderTodos()

// Set up search text handler

document.querySelector('#search-todos').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    setFilters({
        searchText: e.target.value
    })
    renderTodos()
})

// Set up checkbox handler

document.querySelector('#hide-completed').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    setFilters({
        hideCompleted: e.target.checked
    })
    renderTodos()
})

// Set up form submission handler

document.querySelector('#add-todo').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const text = e.target.elements.addTodoText.value.trim()
    createTodo(text)
    e.target.elements.addTodoText.value = ''
})
```

The errors in the chrome debugger console im getting are:

```
views.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _todos.getTodos) is not a function
    at Object../src/views.js (views.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../src/todos.js (todos.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (bundle.js:20254)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:68
    at bootstrap:68
```

I'm just trying to understand why this strange behavior is happening, because once I use getTodos inside `renderTodos` it actually works and I'm not getting any errors, like this:

```
const renderTodos = () => {
    const todos = getTodos()
    // Other stuffs
}
```

I'm using Babel and Webpack.

Comment: You don't export `getTodos`, so you can't import it in the other file.

Comment: I have exported getTodos but i didnt show it in the code above sorry about that I forgot to add that in the end

Comment: Thanks, can you show where all you're using `renderTodos` in the `todos.js`? Figuring that out will reveal how things can be refactored

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added all the files which using renderTodos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you have a circular dependency. For a more minimal example which can illustrate the problem, consider:

```
// foo.js
import bar from './bar';
const x = bar();
export default () => x;

// bar.js
import foo from './foo';
const y = foo();
export default () => y;
```

In the above code, just like in your code, you have modules which are using an import, where said import *also* depends on importing something from the current module. If A imports from B, and B also imports from A, then you need to make sure that neither A nor B use anything from each other before both of their top-level code has finished completely - otherwise, you can't depend on the other import being defined at that time.

It would be best to refactor the code to remove the circular dependency somehow.

A pattern I like to use is to make sure top-level code in a module does not initiate anything - rather, it's nice when everything can ultimately kicked off from the *entry point* (which, here, looks to be `index.js`). A quick fix would be for each module to export a *function* which runs the initialization code, rather than putting that code on the top level. For example:

```
// views.js

import { getTodos, saveTodos, toggleTodo, removeTodo  } from './todos'
import { getFilters } from './filters'

let todos;
const init = () => {
  todos = getTodos();
};
// ... everything else
export { generateSummaryDOM, renderTodos, generateTodoDOM, init }
```

Then have `index.js` import and call `init` at the very beginning, right after importing everything.

Luckily, since `todos.js` only calls (the cross-module, imported) `renderTodos` in its `createTodo` function, and `createTodo` is exported but not called in `todos.js`, it doesn't need to be changed.

Another (probably better) option would be to remove `todos.js`'s dependancy on `renderTodos`. In `todos.js`, you're currently only using `renderTodos` in its `createTodo` function. Consider changing thigns so that `createTodo` creates and saves the todo, but does not render it with `renderTodos`- instead, look for where `createTodo` is used (which looks to be only in `index.js`), and have `index.js` call `renderTodos` instead:

```
// todos.js

// do not import renderTodos here

// ...
const createTodo = (text) => {
    if (text.length > 0) {
        todos.push({
            id: uuidv4(),
            text,
            completed: false
        })
        saveTodos()
    }
}
```

and

```
// index.js

// ...
document.querySelector('#add-todo').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const text = e.target.elements.addTodoText.value.trim()
    createTodo(text)
    renderTodos();
    e.target.elements.addTodoText.value = ''
})
```

Comment: Yes, It actually worked! need to mention that I needed to also remove the `import { renderTodos } from `./views` from `todos.js`. even though the function was not being used at all but having that code in place would mess things up.